# Licensing: Boost library distributed with my MIT-licensed code

Tags: licensing, mit-license, boost

I want to release some C++ code under MIT license in GitHub. I would like to include required BOOST libraries in the repository. No commercial use is currently foreseen. I am pretty new to IP issues, sorry if these questions are obvious.

1. Can I freely redistribute BOOST binaries in my GitHub repository?
2. Do I need to include the BOOST license additionally to the MIT license for my code?

Comment: Have you read the [boost software license](http://www.boost.org/users/license.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.Can I freely redistribute BOOST binaries in my GitHub repository?**

Yes, you can. The Boost software license reads (emphasis mine):

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person or organization
>   obtaining a copy of the software and accompanying documentation covered by
>   this license (the "Software") to use, reproduce, display, **distribute**,
>   execute, and transmit the Software, and to **prepare derivative works** of the
>   Software, and to permit third-parties to whom the Software is furnished to
>   do so

**2.Do I need to include the BOOST license additionally to the MIT license for my code?**

The license continues:

> all subject to the following:
>
> The copyright notices in the Software and this entire statement,
>   including the above license grant, this restriction and the following
>   disclaimer, **must be included** in all copies of the Software, in whole
>   or in part, and all derivative works of the Software, **unless such
>   copies or derivative works are solely in the form of
>   machine-executable object code generated by a source language
>   processor**.

Which means that your sourcecode repository must include the license, but you don't have to add the license to any compiled binaries you provide.

And by the way: The fact that "no commercial use is currently foreseen" is usually irrelevant when it comes to open source software. Part of [the open source definition](https://opensource.org/osd) by the OSI is:

> No Discrimination Against Fields of Endeavor
>
> The license must not restrict anyone from making use of the program in
>   a specific field of endeavor. For example, it may not restrict the
>   program from being used in a business, or from being used for genetic
>   research.

So any license which is approved as open source by the OSI (and [the Boost license is](https://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical)) won't care about any commercial interests you have.

Comment: I had read the license, but I wasn't entirely sure it applied to my case. Thank you!